# hibernate auditions generating same rev id in for multiple insert in one table

Tags: java, hibernate, audit

I am using hibernate auditions with hibernate version 3.5. while it is working fine when I try to insert single record in one table in one transation but the problem is when a "BATCH" runs 
and it inserts multiple records in one table in single transation then **single** "rev id" is being generated for audit tables which causes "integrityconstraintsviolation".

As it is the normal behavior of hibernate that all the insert queries are fired at the end of tansaction(When it flushes) but at this time only one query is being fired for "rev id" generation.

```
 select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual;
```

Kindly tell me whether is it a bug in audit or i am missing something ??
Thanks in advance

Comment: revid is not enver, revid is auditions.

Answer (score 1):

A revid always span modifications in multiple tables!

Yes, the inserts are called at the end of the transaction, but: If you use optimistic transaction isolation, a transaction can read the uncommitted state of another transactions that are currently active but not yet committed.

If you become a integrityconstraintsviolation the column `rev_id` is unfortunatelly configured "unique". This is a wrong database schema! Correct the schema by removing the Uniqueness of the column `rev_id`!

The `rev_id`-Column in the global-hibernate-relationtable **must** be unique because it is a Primary-Key! (the global-hibernate-relationtable usually contains also a timestamp).

Comment: Here I am talking about the "rev" column in audit tables. These tables(Schema) are automatically generated by hibernate envers. We have not created the schema so we cant remove the uniqueness constraint. I suspect that it is envers that recognize it as one insert statement where as multiple inserts have been called.

Comment: Maybe this is a bug, what database are you using? What type is the database-column rev_id in the audited tables?

Comment: We are using Oracle 11g. "rev" column is of "number" datatype.

Comment: @rishi Again: Hibernate Envers will not create the Schema, Hibernate Auditions does it!

Comment: @rishi Indeed its a bug, please report it to Hibernate! As you can see in http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/#schema the `Address_AUD` and the `Person_AUD` has their `REV` not unique!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if still you have this issue :). In my case I had same problem, and solution was to setting on audit table composite primary key on "rev" and "id" columns.
Below example Liquibase script:

```
<addPrimaryKey
    columnNames="id, rev"
    constraintName="t_order_aud_pk"
    tableName="t_order_aud"/>
```